# Transform data from a column, to individual dummy variables accumulating counts by group

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

As in my example below, I have a data table (let's call it "current") that has multiple rows for 3 different people, each with a date and a categorical event. We can assume that I've already sorted it chronologically as below, but that might not matter.

I would like to, for each row, have separate columns for each of the categorical event types that sum the number of times each person has encountered that event up to that point in time (let's call this output data table "desired").

I wrote some code that does it via a loop, but given my data size (millions of rows) it obviously did not go well... What is a proper data manipulation method that I can apply to data table "current" to transform it into data table "desired"?

EDIT: I should have mentioned that my original dataset includes columns that need to be carried over into the final result. My apologies for not including this originally.

```
library(data.table)

current <- data.table(
  person.id = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
  event = factor(c("categoryA", "categoryA", "categoryD", 
                   "categoryA", "categoryC", "categoryB")),
  date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-03-23", "2020-09-09", 
                   "2020-12-30", "2021-06-03", "2022-03-22"))
)

desired <- current |>
  someManipulation(...)

print(current)
print(desired)
```

(Output)

```
   person.id     event       date
1:         1 categoryA 2020-01-01
2:         2 categoryA 2020-03-23
3:         3 categoryD 2020-09-09
4:         1 categoryA 2020-12-30
5:         2 categoryC 2021-06-03
6:         3 categoryB 2022-03-22

   person.id     event       date categoryA categoryB categoryC categoryD
1:         1 categoryA 2020-01-01         1         0         0         0
2:         2 categoryA 2020-03-23         1         0         0         0
3:         3 categoryD 2020-09-09         0         0         0         1
4:         1 categoryA 2020-12-30         2         0         0         0
5:         2 categoryC 2021-06-03         1         0         1         0
6:         3 categoryB 2022-03-22         0         1         0         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create columns based on values of `event` and assign 1 to them if the column name is equal to `event` value in each row. Then you can use `cumsum` by `person.id` to accumulate the values.

```r
library(data.table)

categories <- sort(as.character(unique(current$event)))

current[, (categories) := lapply(
                            lapply(categories, function(x) +(event == x)), 
                                 cumsum), .(person.id)][]

#>    person.id     event       date categoryA categoryB categoryC categoryD
#> 1:         1 categoryA 2020-01-01         1         0         0         0
#> 2:         2 categoryA 2020-03-23         1         0         0         0
#> 3:         3 categoryD 2020-09-09         0         0         0         1
#> 4:         1 categoryA 2020-12-30         2         0         0         0
#> 5:         2 categoryC 2021-06-03         1         0         1         0
#> 6:         3 categoryB 2022-03-22         0         1         0         1
```

If you prefer `dcast`, and want to preserve the order and avoid date conflicts, try adding a row id number prior to `dcast`.

```r
result  <- dcast(current[, rid := .I], 
                    rid + person.id + date + event ~ event, 
                    fun = length)[, rid := NULL][]

cols <- setdiff(names(result), names(current))

result[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = person.id, .SDcols = cols][]

#>    person.id       date     event categoryA categoryB categoryC categoryD
#> 1:         1 2020-01-01 categoryA         1         0         0         0
#> 2:         2 2020-03-23 categoryA         1         0         0         0
#> 3:         3 2020-09-09 categoryD         0         0         0         1
#> 4:         1 2020-12-30 categoryA         2         0         0         0
#> 5:         2 2021-06-03 categoryC         1         0         1         0
#> 6:         3 2022-03-22 categoryB         0         1         0         1
```

Although, I find it hard to believe that `dcast` is faster:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  M_categories = {
    categories <- sort(as.character(unique(current$event)))
    current[, (categories) := lapply(
                                lapply(categories, function(x) event == x),
                                cumsum), .(person.id)]
  },
  
  M_dcast = {
    result  <- dcast(current[, rid := .I], 
                        rid + person.id + date + event ~ event, 
                        fun = length)[, rid := NULL][]
    cols <- setdiff(names(result), names(current))
    result[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = person.id, .SDcols = cols][]
  },
  
  GT_dcats = {
    result = dcast(current, formula = person.id + date ~ event, fun.aggregate = length)
    cols = names(result)[names(result) %like% "category"]
    result[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = person.id, .SDcols = cols]
  }
  )

Unit: microseconds
         expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 M_categories  563.4  600.45  655.900  626.15  651.95  1302.0   100
      M_dcast 3963.3 4235.40 4627.580 4443.90 4620.25 15476.1   100
     GT_dcats 3355.5 3554.40 4030.594 3711.10 3929.75 14002.1   100
```

Even for a larger dataset, `dcast` is noticeably slower:

```
large_data <- current[sample(nrow(current), 10000, replace = TRUE), ]

microbenchmark(
  M_categories = {
    categories <- sort(as.character(unique(large_data$event)))
    large_data[, (categories) := lapply(
                                lapply(categories, function(x) event == x),
                                cumsum), .(person.id)]
  },

  M_dcast = {
    result  <- dcast(large_data[, rid := .I], 
                        rid + person.id + date + event ~ event, 
                        fun = length)[, rid := NULL][]
    cols <- setdiff(names(result), names(large_data))
    result[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = person.id, .SDcols = cols][]
  },

  GT_dcats = {
    result = dcast(large_data, formula = person.id + date ~ event, fun.aggregate = length)
    cols = names(result)[names(result) %like% "category"]
    result[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = person.id, .SDcols = cols]
  }
  )

Unit: milliseconds
         expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
 M_categories  1.4199  1.65105  2.23003  1.98575  2.45670 10.9188   100
      M_dcast 26.1525 27.53905 28.46625 28.07925 28.64415 36.4706   100
     GT_dcats  4.3829  4.94760  5.49732  5.44890  5.78995 15.0705   100
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Oooh, I bet this is **much** more efficient than my `dcast`.

Comment: Thanks for this second option. This one also keeps the original event column and sorting intact. I will try both and see which is faster on my real dataset. Much thanks, I appreciate the manipulation skills.

Comment: This method takes much longer than the `dcast` (multiple minutes vs. <1 minute), but it keeps the other columns of the data table intact and doesn't have issues with a person.id having multiple events on the same date. This is the preferred solution.

Comment: @Matt see my updates.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dcast` to one-hot-encode the `event` column and then `cumsum` by person id to get the cumulative count of events.

```
result = dcast(current, formula = person.id + date ~ event, fun.aggregate = length)

cols = names(result)[names(result) %like% "category"]
result[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = person.id, .SDcols = cols]
result
#    person.id       date categoryA categoryB categoryC categoryD
# 1:         1 2020-01-01         1         0         0         0
# 2:         1 2020-12-30         2         0         0         0
# 3:         2 2020-03-23         1         0         0         0
# 4:         2 2021-06-03         1         0         1         0
# 5:         3 2020-09-09         0         0         0         1
# 6:         3 2022-03-22         0         1         0         1
```

Comment: Magic! I used `cols <- current$event |> levels()` for my situation given that my column names are not as straightforward as the example I provided.

Comment: UPDATE: On my actual dataset, some rows are dropped from the result. Perhaps because some number of them share identical person.id's and dates. Also, I should have added to my original question that there are other columns in the data that I would like to keep around. I have updated my original question to reflect this.

Comment: For the `dcast` to work, you need a unique identifier or combination of columns that make a unique identifer on the LHS of the formula.  If you don't have a unique identifier in your data, you can just add the row number, but it's usually a good idea to have one. And you can get the rest of your columns with join back to the original data.

Comment: If you `setkey` on the original table with your unique identifier(s), it might keep it sorted.